Requesting money after an accident and refusing to go through insurance
I was trying to avoid someone driving in front of me from hitting me and allegedly backed into someone driving behind me.  I didn't see anyone behind me but was also focused more on trying to avoid an accident in front of me particularly with my elderly mother in the car.  I gave the person my contact and insurance information, but she didn't give me hers and talked about not wanting to go through insurance.  I had no damage to my truck and didn't see much of any damage at all to her vehicle outside of maybe a scratch or two and didn't think much of it and figured if she had any issues, she would just contact my insurance company.  Almost a month after all this, I get a text from her showing me a mechanic bill for almost $2000.  I talked to her on the phone, and she said that her check engine light came on immediately after the accident, but she didn't want to go through insurance because she was afraid it would diminish the value of her car if she wanted to sell it, and wanted to know what cash I could give her to compensate.  I have told her repeatedly to contact my insurance company, but she has refused, and she has also refused to give me her insurance information.  Now she is telling me I have 10 days to get her the money.  Her father is a lawyer, so I am assuming her "or else" is taking me to court.  Does she have a case and what should I do.

Refusing to give insurance information may be a violation of the law.

Her father may be a lawyer, but he will not want to end up like the lawyer in the infamous “trousers” case. Guess what a judge in court would do if you hand the judge your insurance information.

@gnasher729 indeed.  They don't have a case for claiming from his own insurance company.

Of course she has a case
She asserts that you backed into her car and caused damage - that’s a very clear legal cause of action. There is no doubt she has a case.
She would have to prove you hit her and that the repair costs are reasonable but based on what you have said, it seems likely she can do this.
What should you do?
We can’t give you legal advice.
Insurance
You seem to misunderstand how insurance works.
You caused the damage, therefore, her cause of action is against you. Whether you or she has insurance, or whether the insured chooses to involve their insurer, is irrelevant. The insurer’s role is to indemnify the insured, that is, to run the case and meet the costs on behalf of the insured. it is you that she has a cause of action against, not your insurer.
If the claim is coming from the plaintiff's insurer, it is common practice for them to just deal with the defendant's insurer right out of the gate in an attempt to resolve the matter without litigation. But there is generally no obligation for someone bringing a claim to first deal with the defendant's insurer. Once the defendant brings their insurer into the loop, they can direct all communications to the appointed adjuster or lawyer.
You should definitely check your policy because you almost surely have an obligation to inform your insurer of what’s happening, even if you do not intend to claim.

Someone would have a case even if they repeatedly refused to let insurance handle the issue as is normally expected?

@JoeW if Alice crashes her car into Bob's car then Bob can seek damages from Alice.  If Alice is insured, she can file a claim with her insurer.  The insurer will probably want to deal with Bob's insurer.  If Bob doesn't want his insurer to be involved, then Alice may have some leverage: "I will forward any demand for damages to my insurer" -- maybe at that point, Bob will decide not to seek compensation from Alice.  It's certainly not for Bob to demand that Alice forgo the insurance coverage that she purchased.

@phoog I understand that, but what I am asking about is if Bob keeps demanding that Alice just pay out cash doesn't that impact his ability to make a claim?

@phoog, you have flipped the roles in a way that is confusing.  The bottom line is that insurance companies will not pay for a claim that another insurance company has already paid. Therefore, the insurance companies need to talk to each other.  If the plaintiff in this case is refusing to facilitate that cooperation between insurance companies then her only option is to extort cash from the individual which is what she seems to be attempting.

@JoeW not really.  Bob's underlying claim is against Alice.  Alice's insurer has no direct liability to Bob; their responsibility is to cover Alice's liability.  Bob is under no obligation to deal with Alice's insurer.

@MichaelHall what roles have I flipped?  Alice has liability to Bob for damaging his car.  Alice's insurer has an obligation to cover Alice's liability.  I agree that Alice's insurer will want to be certain that Bob hasn't already had the claim covered by his own insurance, which Alice should also want to know.  But if Alice makes the claim, then her insurer will deal with Bob (assuming Bob refuses to identify his insurer) and she won't have to.

@phoog so you are saying one party can refuse to accept the standard method for handling payment for damages and still hold the other party liable even though they tried to get it paid? If would be different if the insurance company refused to pay instead of one party refusing to let them get involved

@JoeW the liable party is liable. The liable party's insurer may cover the liability.  The party that suffered damages can't prevent the liable party from seeking reimbursement from the liable party's insurer.  The damaged party can choose not to tell her own insurer, but she can't "refuse to let the insurance companies get involved" generally.

@phoog, You flipped the genders of the people in the example. Yes, it's not that difficult to figure out, but if you're familiar with the original question it did take a little back and forth to be sure your point was clear.  There was just no compelling reason to do so in my opinion... FWIW.

@MichaelHall sorry.  I just called Alice "Alice" because I mentioned her first.
